Azure container registry monitor
Is there any way to monitor azure container registry health constantly(not very big fan of azure cli command)
The standard metrics is only helpful for used registries but what if someone wants to check health of unused registries

Follow the instructions from this link to monitor your acr- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/monitor-service and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-check-health

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As far as I know Azure does not provide any option to monitor unused registries at the moment. Max you can do is manage your deleted repositories. But to monitor your azure container registry, with active repositories in it, you can use azure monitor.
Search for monitor in azure and create a new rule, set the scope i.e. which resource you want to monitor which in this case will be your acr name.

Under conditions, choose what all you want alerts for example- you might set up alerts for metrics like "Push Count" or "Pull Count" being at zero over a specific period.

Under action group, choose how you want to be notified (email, SMS, etc.)

Once done configuring the alert rule details (name, description, severity) and create the alert rule. Wait for sometime as it takes few mins to create. Done.


one more simple way is to use Monitor under your acr as shown below

Here I selected push count metric. you can play around with whatever metric you wish to monitor.
or from CLI you can do to check the health of your registry.
az acr check-health --name myregistry

References:

Monitor Azure Container Registry
Check the health of an Azure container registry

